# Is that good to use driver.manage().window().maximize() in selenium for every time we invoke browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

We use `driver.manage().window().maximize();` to maximize the browser.

I have seen few examples online that are using `driver.manage().window().maximize()` though it's not required to maximize the browser. (For Ex: gmail login)

Also I see on invoking browser using selenium it opens in maximized window only. Still I have to use this `driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: Not only did this not work, it stopped the rest of the java code from executing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Little longer answer: when selenium is interacting with the web page, like clicking on button or writing to text field, the interacted `WebElement` must be visible, or you will get exception. If you think on performance calling one time to `window().maximize()` is much 'cheaper' (and much less prone to errors) than scrolling to the `WebElement` every time.

You gave Gmail login as example, but usually you need to do more than just login in tests project.

By the way

> Also I see on invoking browser using selenium it opens in maximized window only

Is not true.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your choice. If window is not maximized, probably You might not be able to find element on page. So if you need such element then it worth to maximize window.

Answer (score 0):

As [pratapvaibhav19] said, it's totally depends on your choice. 
There are different ways of doing this, you can open maximized Chrome windows. For Firefox and IE you can use driver.manage().window().maximize();. Alternatively you can open browser window as per your screen resolution OR in custom size.

Comment: @NickQ I don't ​agree with you, I'm afraid. I just executed my script (which was working properly with maximized browser window) on Chrome without maximizing the browser window. But it didn't work. I checked several times but every time it threw TargetInvocationException. Therefore, I am afraid what you are saying will work for all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* have to maximize the window. 
Selenium can interact with the browser in any screen resolution, because it doesn't use the mouse or keyboard like desktop automation tools.

It's just easier to view web pages and take screenshots on bigger browser windows.