# Windows Key+Up Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I need to use the `windows` key + `up` to so I can maximise my window. However there is no option for a `windows` key

```
driver.keyboard.sendkeys(Keys.);
```

Not sure if there is a way around this.

Comment: Can you maximize your window before you run your selenium test case? Why do you need to maximize it on the fly? Selenium does not have access to your system. It has access to your webpage. If you want something to send system keys, I recommend using AutoHotKey - you can use that to do many things, including send keys, as well as launch you selenium script (assuming you are using the stand-alone plugin). If you are doing this from the Selenium server product, I think you are out of luck. Again, why do you need the window maximized?

Comment: Do you need to use keys? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882935/is-that-good-to-use-driver-manage-window-maximize-in-selenium-for-every-ti

Comment: @AdamEdison-MusicEducator I need to make sure the window is maximized because I can't see the element I need if it's not

Comment: @RobbieToyota I tried that however I get the following error `Indicates that a command that should have executed properly cannot be supported for some reason."}}`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually sending keys, there are many other ways to `Maximize` the browser window. Here's what I recommend:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

---

Other methods include:

Setting the `Size` manually:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
```

Via `IJavaScriptExecutor`:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(1024, 768);");
```

Via `ChromeOptions`:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArgument("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```